# Decimal separator missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-server-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

When i publish and run my app on production server decimal separator (for decimal type numbers) is disappearing (for background calculations and for for display).
eg: 26,1205 -> 261205

It only happens on remote Windows Server 2019 Standard. That's what I did, but it doesn't help still:

I set `CultureInfo` for application in `Startup.cs` in `Configure` method:

```
var defaultDateCulture = "ru-RU"; //no matter what culture is set here (en, ru, etc), it applied locally but not on production
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { ci },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { ci }
});
```

I checked region settings on windows server:
[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly because the locale its using has a comma as a thousands separator. The conversion of the decimal to a string is perhaps happening on a different thread with a different culture than the one you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user mr. Matthew Watson for guiding me right.

App executes delayed scheduled background task for currency operations (using `BackgroundService` class). The problem was actual for that thread. So i explicitly set `CultureInfo` right before performing operations.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    ...
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    ...
}
```